# How to watch changes on a global server-side variable in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular, electron

I'm creating an app with Angular 2 using Electron & Node. There are tests that run on the server and the results get output one by one into a global variable array called testResults. I have no problem pulling that into Angular using:

```
declare var testResults: any;
```

However, I have had no luck getting Angular to trigger an event when an Object is added to the array. Is there a way I can watch for changes on this array? I've tried onChanges and doCheck but have had no luck.

This is what I have for my component:

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange, OnInit} from         'angular2/core';

declare var testResults: any;

@Component({
 selector: 'test-results',
 template: `{{ testResultsItem }}
 `,
})

export class TestResultsComponent implements OnChanges{
  @Input () testResultsItem = testResults;

ngOnChanges(changes: {[ propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    console.log('Change detected:', changes[this.testResultsItem].currentValue);
    console.log(this.testResultsItem);
 }
}
```

When I run a setInterval that logs that array in the console every second I do see the changes to the array in the console. They also update in the DOM under {{testResults}}. But there should be a way that angular detects this change instead of running a setInterval, correct? Any help would be appreciated!

Here is when I tried using IterableDiffers:

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange, OnInit, IterableDiffers, ChangeDetectorRef, IterableDiffer, Directive, DoCheck} from 'angular2/core';

declare var testResults: any;

@Component({
selector: 'test-results',
template: `{{ testResultsItem | json }}
 `,
inputs: ['testResults']
 })

export class TestResultsComponent implements DoCheck{

private testResultsItem = testResults;
private differ:IterableDiffer;
constructor(private changeDetector:ChangeDetectorRef, private differs:IterableDiffers) {
 this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);
}

set testReults(test:any) {
    this.testResultsItem = test;
    if (test && !this.differ) {
      this.differ = this.differs.find(test).create(this.changeDetector);
    }
}
ngDoCheck(){
    if (this.differ) {
        const changes = this.differ.diff(this.testResultsItem);
        if (changes) {
            console.log('FIRE!');
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Angular doesn't check for changes inside objects or array. It only checks if an object reference has checked. You can use the `IterableDiffer` to check for changes in `ngDoCheck`. Please post the code that demonstrates what you have tried. Where is the code that changes `testResults`?

Comment: testResults is created in a main.js file that is linked in the index. From there is calls to a js file called reporter.js that returns the objects in the array.

I tried to implement with IterableDiffer: Unfortunately Im still not getting it to fire. I added the code above to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your tempalte to

```
template: `{{ testResultsItem | json }}
```

then Angular2 should detect the changes

Comment: I tried this and it still did not log any 'change detected' strings in the console

Comment: What about my questions in the comment above? If you change an input in your code `ngOnChanges` is not called. It is only called when `valueFromParent` in `<test-results [testResultsItem]="valueFromParent">` changes and change detection updates the binding. You can make `testResultsItem` a setter to execute code every time a new value is assigned.

Comment: I just attempted IterableDiffers but was not able to get it to fire on changes to the array. I posted the code above in the original question. When you say valueFromParent what are you referring to? Like a click event from the Parent Component? Should I be using this with ngOnChange or with IterableDiffers and DoCheck?

Comment: You are missing the initialization of the differ. See `constructor` in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html

Comment: Thanks, I see. I added `this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);` inside the constructor but it is still not firing. I modified the code above to reflect this.

Comment: Is `ngDoCheck()` being called at all?

Comment: Yes, the class implements DoCheck and there is a DoCheck at the bottom of the class in the code above. Is there an additional way I need to call it?

Comment: The question was if it actually gets called. Just add a `consile.log('xxx')` and check if it gets printed.

Comment: It does print a couple times on load and a few times while the test is running after a click event triggers the test function. However, the changes are not fired when the objects are being added to the array.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks anyways. I appreciate it!